# Random variable: $X\sim Normal(m, {\sigma}^2)$, find the characteristic function of $X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is it possible, knowing that $X$ is a random variable with normal distribution( with parameters $(m, {\sigma}^2)$), to find the characteristic function of $X^2$ ?

What I thought is:

Since: $\phi_X(t) = E[e^{itX}]\space$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, then $\phi_{X^2}(t) = E[e^{itX^2}]$. $\phi$ is the characteristic function.

$$E[e^{itX^2}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx^2}\cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$

I know how to find the characteristic function for $X$, when I make the substitution: $y = \frac{x-m}{\sigma}$, but here I cannot find the right one, so that I could finally get something. Can you, please, suggest something ? Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to start with a standard normal. Then at least you know the characteristic function should be $(1 - 2it)^{-1/2}$